# How do I make cucumber exit a scenario?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, cucumber

I have a scenario outline. I want to skip certain steps for certain scenarios. I used Cucumber.wants_to_quit but it doesn't seem to work. Steps mentioned after this method are run anyway for all scenarios.
I'm using Ruby, selenium, cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [Directly from the Docs](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/skip-scenario) on how to create a feature that would allow you to skip:

Given a file named "feature/test.feature"

```
Feature: test
  Scenario: test
    Given this step says to skip
    And this step passes
```

Using standard step defintions and with a file such as "features/step_definitions/skippy.rb" with:

```
Given /skip/ do
  skip_this_scenario
end
```

if you run `cucmber -q`
then the previous would pass as:

```
Feature: test

  Scenario: test
    Given this step says to skip
    And this step passes

1 scenario (1 skipped)
2 steps (2 skipped)
0m0.012s
```